# How to center align delegates from GridView

Tags: qt, qml

I want to align all delegates inside a GridView to center

I have tried:

```
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
anchors.centerIn: parent
anchors.fill: parent
```

I have so

[image]

I want so

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need a calculate how many items are on the last row and how many empty slots there are (in the example above = 2).  I would then add "ghost" delegates that are slotted into those gaps  to centre the visible items on the bottom row.  Obviously you wouldn't need to add in the "ghost" delegates to the end as that would make no difference.  So given the example above, slot in a "ghost" delegate at index 7.

Comment: thank you @teh_raab, not bad idea